# sharepoint server 2013 error Session state disabled for asp.net

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, asp.net, session

I am getting error on my sharepoint server 2013 "Session state has been disabled for ASP.NET.  The Report Viewer control requires that session state be enabled in local mode."

For that error i have tried for , changes in web.config like enableSessionState="true" also tried with power shell command like

`"Enable-SPSessionStateService –Defaultprovision"` but same error appearing.

what will be the issue ? please suggest me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In SharePoint 2013, try to do the following:**

- Open the SharePoint web application `web.config`.
- In the `<system.web>` section, find the `<httpModules>` element and edit it like the following:

  ```
  <httpModules> <add name = "Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" /></httpModules>
  ```
- Below `<system.web>` , at  `<pages>` and set the `enableSessionState` attribute to **true**
- Save and close the web.config file.
- Now open IIS > Sites > select your SharePoint web application.
- Open the modules applet under the IIS section.
- Click `Add Managed Module` in the right-hand panel.
- Enter a name for the module> at `Type`, try to type `System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule`, then select the below namespace

  ```
  System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
  ```

  [image]
- Perform `IISReset`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. solved my disable error. but now i am getting report viewer configuration error
i have added tags to the system.web/httpHandlers and to the system.webServer/handlers section as on error i am getting.

Comment: @user71032 Glad it helps! Now you should close this question by setting the answer as accepted (the true sign beside my answer) then create a new question with the new query/error with more details!

Comment: Hello Qassas, above changes for IIS can be done easily on window server 2012 which i have tested but for window server 2008 R2 do we need to do something extra ? because on server 2008 R2 i am not getting "Add managed modules" predefined types on drop down list to select type ?

Comment: Do you have SharePoint 2013 with Windows Server 2008 R2?!

Comment: yes, Sharepoint 2013 installed on server 2008 R2